# Как в Delphi повернуть WinControl на 45 градусов?

Tags: delphi, winapi

Как повернуть WinControl на 45 градусов?

Comment: Простой ответ - никак. Сложный ответ - с дикими костылями, можно попробовать, но проще будет свой контрол сделать.